# How do I create an encrypted PayPal button dynamically in Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, encryption, paypal, pkcs#7

So far I have found an [example](http://jonatkinson.co.uk/paypal-encrypted-buttons-django/) for Django that uses [M2Crypto](http://sandbox.rulemaker.net/ngps/m2/), but because M2Crypto is based on a C library, it cannot be run on GAE. Does anyone have a working code for creating an encrypted PayPal button dynamically in Google App Engine?

In a nutshell, I need to translate the following Ruby code into Python. It's taken from [PayPal's Website Payments Standard toolkit](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/library_download_sdks#WPST) for Ruby.

```
def self.encrypt_data(paypal_cert, my_business_cert, my_business_key,
                      my_business_key_password, myparams  )     
  paypal_cert      = OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new(paypal_cert)     
  my_business_cert = OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new(my_business_cert)      
  my_business_key  = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(
    my_business_key,
    my_business_key_password)   
  info = ""
  myparams.each_pair {|key,value| info << "#{key}=#{value}\n"}    
  signedInfo       = OpenSSL::PKCS7::sign(
    my_business_cert,
    my_business_key,
    info,
    [],
    OpenSSL::PKCS7::BINARY)
  OpenSSL::PKCS7::encrypt(
    [paypal_cert],
    signedInfo.to_der,
    OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher::new("DES3"),
    OpenSSL::PKCS7::BINARY)           
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look to [Keyczar](http://www.keyczar.org/) library, it should work on Google App Engine allowing you to sign using *RSA* and encrypt with *DES3* .

Check the documentation [here](http://keyczar.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/python/doc/pycrypt.pdf).